# Should I join a thread that has been killed?

Tags: c++, c, pthreads, rtai, lxrt

I have many *joinable* threads that at some point need to all stop. The threads are pthread, but are created through RTAI's user-space interface (never mind the RTAI though).

For each thread I have a variable that I can set to tell them to quit. So what I do is:

- set that variable for each thread so that they stop
- Wait at most one second
- join the threads

Now the thing is, since I am using RTAI, which uses a kernel-space buddy thread to the work for me, if something goes wrong, the thread may go unresponsive (It has never happened, but I have to be careful just in case something DOES go wrong). In such a case, I just kill the thread.

**So, my question is, once you have a thread that is killed, should you `join` on it or not?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Killing a thread doesn't change whether you should join it or not.  If
the thread hasn't been detached, then you need to join it, or you will leak
resources in the system.

Comment: There is no such thing as "killing a thread", so I'm not sure what this answer (or even the question) means...

Comment: Presumably, he means `pthread_cancel` (but of course, a thread won't necessarily react to that).